# Python multiple inheritance super function caling order

Tags: python

I wonder hot it comes in such order that `enter C enter A leave A leave C` ?
Who called `C.__init__()` ?Why is it right after B before A?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter A')
        print('leave A')


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter B')
        super().__init__()
        print('leave B')


class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter C')
        super().__init__()
        print('leave C')


class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter D')
        super().__init__()
        print('leave D')


d = D()
```

The result is as following:

```
enter D
enter B
enter C
enter A
leave A
leave C
leave B
leave D
```

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C3_linearization, which guarantees that the method resolution order satisfies two conditions: 1) each class precedes its parents, and 2) the order of base classes is preserved. In this case, `D` precedes `B` and `C`, `B` and `C` both precede `A`, `A` precedes `object`, and `B` precedes `C`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `super().__init__`'s location, it's in the middle of the two `print` functions, this will send it to another class before your `print` for leaving the class, so do:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter A')
        print('leave A')

class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter B')
        print('leave B')
        super().__init__()

class C(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter C')
        print('leave C')
        super().__init__()

class D(B, C):
    def __init__(self):
        print('enter D')
        print('leave D')
        super().__init__()


d = D()
```

Output:

```
enter D
leave D
enter B
leave B
enter C
leave C
enter A
leave A
```

Also why `B` before `A`, because it processes the two sub-classes first, see @chepner's comment for more info.